# Where to call mailer in Rails after model creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, controller, actionmailer

So on a form submission which creates a new model, I want to email the user saying the new appointment has been submitted and also add a link to the new appointment.  Where should I put the logic of emailing the user?  Right now I have in the new method of the appointments_controller but I'm not sure if that's the right place?  Also, how do I generate the correct url?  This is what I have right now.

```
def new
  url = "www.example.com/appointments/#{Appointment.last.id + 1}"
  MyMailer.send_email(current_user, url).deliver
end
```

Comment: Have you read [Action Mailer Basics from Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)? - 1Section 2.1.4 Calling the Mailer1 clearly shows how to do this

Comment: Oh wow I'm an idiot.  Yes I read some parts of it but not all.  Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You should call the myMailer method from the create action in the appointments_controller in the

```
if @appointment.save
```

block.  You generate the correct url by calling current_user.email I would presume.

Comment: So the controller has access to the object being created?  Also, for the url,  I want to give them the url to the new appointment.  So for example, if they're the 5th appointment, I want them to get /appointments/5.  What I did up in my original post is just get the last id of all appointments then incremented that.... Idk if that's safe or not because that url technically doesn't exist yet